# print value before return

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I have a python function

```
def foo():
    '''
     some code
    '''

    return handle.fetch_some_result()
```

and I want to achieve the goal:

```
def foo():
    '''
     some code
    '''

    value = handle.fetch_some_result()
    print value
    return value
```

So how can I achieve this but not use the above code(a little ugly). 
Are there some elegant ways to do that but not use the middle var(`value`) or is it possible in python?

Thx!

Comment: What is your actual problem here? You want to print *and* return the value? Then you have few options but to either call the method again or use a local variable.

Comment: What you are doing is the normal way. It isn't ugly (if ugliness is defined as being unPythonic, if that is defined as following pep8 and the zen of Python). There are no other ways I am aware of except using a variable or calling the method twice. Between those two ways, I personally prefer what you are already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write easily a helper function that does that, I don't know any built-in:

```
def print_return(value):
    print value
    return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with how your doing it. If you don't like the print in the function, you could alwsy print the return value.

```
def foo():
    '''
     some code
    '''

    return handle.fetch_some_result()

result = foo()
print result
```